# how to make a shift of vertically connecting line with nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have made a flow chart but I am not able to shift the connecting line in the [image]following diagram

```
   \begin{figure}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum width=1.7cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,thick,text width=1.9cm,text centered},node distance=.3cm] 
             \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
              \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
               \node[on chain=1](n0) {Training };
               \node[frm](n1) {\scriptsize Construct one gait cycle from all subjects};
               \node[frm](n2) {\scriptsize Find for each subject};
               \node[frm](n3) {\scriptsize Construct set of global};
               \node[frm](n4) {\scriptsize Compute data set domain };

              \end{scope} 
               \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n1] (n7) {\scriptsize Find feature}; 
               \node[boxed,right=.7cm of n2] (n8) {\scriptsize Passed through auto-encoder}; 
               \node at (n0-|n8) (n9) {Test };
               \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n3] (n10) {\scriptsize Classify data through }; 
               \node[boxed,right=0.25cm of n4] (n11) {\scriptsize Trained auto-encoder}; 
               \node[below=2.5cm of n10, trapezium,trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,
                minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,draw,thick] (n14) {\scriptsize Final class};
             \end{scope} 

              \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw,-latex,thick}]  
               \path 
               (n9) edge (n7)
               (n7) edge (n8)
               (n8) edge (n10)
               (n4) edge (n11)
               (n11.north-|n10) edge (n10)
               (n10) edge (n14);
              \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:block1}
    \end{figure}
```

In this code, I want to connect the line between node n10 and node n14 with right alignment, so that the line will not cross the node n11.

how may I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this? You can use `xshift`. I also slightly rearranged your diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,boxed/.style={minimum width=1.7cm,minimum height=1cm,draw,thick,text width=1.9cm,text centered},node distance=.3cm] 
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=upper]
  \begin{scope}[start chain=1 going below,every join/.style={-latex,thick},frm/.style={boxed,on chain=1,join}]
    \node[on chain=1](n0) {Training };
           \node[frm](n1) {\scriptsize Construct one gait cycle from all subjects};
           \node[frm](n2) {\scriptsize Find for each subject};
           \node[frm](n3) {\scriptsize Construct set of global};
           \node[frm](n4) {\scriptsize Compute data set domain };

          \end{scope} 
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n1] (n7) {\scriptsize Find feature}; 
           \node[boxed,right=.7cm of n2] (n8) {\scriptsize Passed through auto-encoder}; 
           \node at (n0-|n8) (n9) {Test };
           \node[boxed,right=0.7cm of n3] (n10) {\scriptsize Classify data through }; 
           \node[boxed,right=0.25cm of n4] (n11) {\scriptsize Trained auto-encoder}; 
           \node[below=2.5cm of n10, trapezium,trapezium left angle=60,trapezium right angle=120,
            minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,draw,thick] (n14) {\scriptsize Final class};
         \end{scope} 

  \begin{scope}[every edge/.style={draw,-latex,thick}]  
   \path 
   (n9) edge (n7)
   (n7) edge (n8)
   (n8) edge (n10)
   (n4) edge (n11)
   (n11.north-|n10) edge (n10)
   ([xshift=-2mm]n10.south east) coordinate(aux) edge (n14.north-|aux);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]